# How to get exit code of piped process?

Tags: go

I wrote a small Go app that reads from `stdin` using the technique outlined here: https://flaviocopes.com/go-shell-pipes/

I invoke it like this: `cmd | fsjl` (where `fsjl` is my app)

Trouble is, the exit code is always `0` even when `cmd` exits `1`.

How can I "forward" the exit code from `cmd`?

[Here is my source code](https://github.com/neezer/fsjl/blob/master/fsjl.go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a job for your Go program. That's a job for whoever's managing the overall pipeline. Pipeline elements don't see each other's exit statuses.

For example, in bash, you can use [`pipefail`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the pipeline exit successfully. This option is disabled by default.

Here's an example, [using a subshell](https://superuser.com/questions/510066/setting-pipefail-for-a-single-piped-command) to restrict the effects of `pipefail` to a single line:

```
(set -o pipefail && cmd | fsjl)
```

You can't always assume bash, but there are [ways](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q11) to do similar things in other shells.